# Timers in Services

Tags: c#, process, timer, server-side

we have recently added a new feature to our software - preview generation for documents that are uploaded and stored on the server. We did this the following way:

1. The user uploads a document;
2. Once the user opens the document information card, the preview for the recently uploaded document is issued (the info regarding the preview generation is stored in a db table);
3. Every 30 seconds our service starts, reviews the preview table and initiates the preview generation procedures.

The problem that I am facing now is this - the new code for generating previews uses some of our legacy code and it sometimes "freezes" the Word or Excel processes. The generation of preview stops and all the following previews stay in "pending" mode until I kill the Word, Excel processes (we test the preview for MS Office documents). After I kill the processes, preview generation continues on.

I was thinking of implementing timers into our service so that if a service is awaiting for more that 1 minute after the preview generation has been started, it should kill the process  and continue on with generating previews for other documents.

The main problem that I have is that i can not "move" the calls to our legacy code to separate processes as we have done with other documents (for example, we have implemented .ps file generation with GhostScript via Process'es).

Any ideas on how to "processify" the calls to legacy code?

Comment: Just to clarify, you said "I can not move the calls to our legacy code to separate processes."  Does this mean you couldn't wrap the calls in an asynchronous thread and just check the status of that thread for a minute and abort the thread if it doesn't complete in time?  This is what struck me as the immediate answer to your question, but if your limited in some way that you are unable to do this could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I can not wrap the call to the legacy code in an asynchronous thread. It is what I initially wanted to do, but was not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make a second process which is a *watchdog* on the first process?

Or can you make the first process auto-restart, and have a second timer thread that monitors it and then kills its own process?

Comment: The auto-restart seems to be quite complicated. I should probably try out the watch-dog approach. Maybe you have some code samples in C#?

Comment: I don't have code I can share, sorry. The way it works though is you start your service, and it starts the watchdog, passing it's own process ID to the watchdog so the latter knows where to look.

Comment: We decided to implement the watch-dog style service to watch over the other process. Thank you!